# Trace inequality for a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, inequality, determinant, symmetric-matrices

Let S be a symmetric positive n×n matrix and $$B \in M_n(R)$$ a triangularizable matrix  with spectrum in $$[0, 1]$$
Prove the inequality:
$$tr(BS)\ge tr(B)\det(S)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not true. Consider
$$
B=\pmatrix{0&1\\ 0&0},\ S=\pmatrix{\frac12&-\frac14\\ -\frac14&\frac12}.
$$
The spectrum of $S$ is $\{\frac14,\frac34\}$ and hence $S$ is positive definite, but $\operatorname{tr}(BS)=-\frac14<0=\operatorname{tr}(B)\det(S)$.